# Extract One Set of Gene Coordinates From a File Containing Several Sets of Gene Coordinates

Tags: awk, data-manipulation

Given the following file:

```
NW_022983499.1  RefSeq  CDS 6883    7503    .   +   0   ID=cds-XP_033376633.1
NW_022983500.1  RefSeq  CDS 5353    5898    .   +   0   ID=cds-XP_033376630.1
NW_022983500.1  RefSeq  CDS 6033    7994    .   +   0   ID=cds-XP_033376630.1
NW_022983502.1  RefSeq  CDS 5391    5543    .   +   0   ID=cds-XP_033376626.1
NW_022983502.1  RefSeq  CDS 5591    5673    .   +   0   ID=cds-XP_033376626.1
NW_022983502.1  RefSeq  CDS 5782    5895    .   +   1   ID=cds-XP_033376626.1
NW_022983502.1  RefSeq  CDS 5937    6424    .   +   1   ID=cds-XP_033376626.1
NW_022983502.1  RefSeq  CDS 6478    6680    .   +   2   ID=cds-XP_033376626.1
NW_022983502.1  RefSeq  CDS 6739    6858    .   +   0   ID=cds-XP_033376626.1
NW_022983502.1  RefSeq  CDS 6926    7408    .   +   0   ID=cds-XP_033376626.1
NW_022983504.1  RefSeq  CDS 5478    5513    .   -   0   ID=cds-XP_033376620.1
NW_022983504.1  RefSeq  CDS 5353    5419    .   -   0   ID=cds-XP_033376620.1
NW_022983504.1  RefSeq  CDS 5161    5297    .   -   2   ID=cds-XP_033376620.1
NW_022983504.1  RefSeq  CDS 5059    5115    .   -   0   ID=cds-XP_033376620.1
NW_022983508.1  RefSeq  CDS 4415    5392    .   -   1   ID=cds-XP_033376609.1
NW_022983508.1  RefSeq  CDS 4215    4344    .   -   1   ID=cds-XP_033376609.1
NW_022983512.1  RefSeq  CDS 2650    2831    .   +   0   ID=cds-XP_033376596.1
NW_022983512.1  RefSeq  CDS 2890    3112    .   +   1   ID=cds-XP_033376596.1
NW_022983512.1  RefSeq  CDS 3163    3267    .   +   0   ID=cds-XP_033376596.1
```

I would like to extract one set of coordinates (from lower to higher numerical value) corresponding to the IDs present in column 9, so as to obtain the following file:

```
NW_022983499.1  RefSeq  CDS 6883    7503    .   +   0   ID=cds-XP_033376633.1
NW_022983500.1  RefSeq  CDS 5353    7994    .   +   0   ID=cds-XP_033376630.1
NW_022983502.1  RefSeq  CDS 5391    7408    .   +   0   ID=cds-XP_033376626.1
NW_022983504.1  RefSeq  CDS 5059    5513    .   -   0   ID=cds-XP_033376620.1
NW_022983508.1  RefSeq  CDS 4215    5392    .   -   0   ID=cds-XP_033376609.1
NW_022983512.1  RefSeq  CDS 2650    3267    .   +   0   ID=cds-XP_033376596.1
```

Note that in the case of `ID=cds-XP_033376630.1` who has a positive value in column 7, I need to select the value of line 2 column 4 `5353` and of line 3 column 5 `7994`.

In contrast, if the value of column 7 is negative, as in `ID=cds-XP_033376620.1`, the logic gets inverted, I need to select the value of line 14, column 4 `5059` and of line 11, column 5 `5513`

I am specially interested in using AWK (not Perl or Python), to solve this classical bioinformatics problem, and I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: How do you determing the 8th field value to be printed? For example for `ID=cds-XP_033376620.1` 2 of the lines have `0` for the 8th field while one of them has `2` and in the output you print `... 0   ID=cds-XP_033376620.1` - why not `... 2   ID=cds-XP_033376620.1`?

Comment: That is a great question. The file format is GFF3 - a classical bioinformatics file format. Here Column 8: "phase" is strictly defined. BUT, for us, in this particular case, **it does not matter**, we can print "0". In fact it should be "0", because we are converting the file to another file format (BED - another Bioinformatics file format) later, and that column will be lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$NF != prevKey {
    if ( NR > 1 ) {
        prt()
    }
    min  = $4
    max  = $5
    line = $0
    prevKey = $NF
}
{
    min = ($4 <= min ? $4 : min)
    max = ($4 >= max ? $5 : max)
}
END { prt() }

function prt(   orig) {
    orig = $0
    $0 = line
    $4 = min
    $5 = max
    $8 = 0
    print
    $0 = orig
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
NW_022983499.1 RefSeq CDS 6883 7503 . + 0 ID=cds-XP_033376633.1
NW_022983500.1 RefSeq CDS 5353 7994 . + 0 ID=cds-XP_033376630.1
NW_022983502.1 RefSeq CDS 5391 7408 . + 0 ID=cds-XP_033376626.1
NW_022983504.1 RefSeq CDS 5059 5513 . - 0 ID=cds-XP_033376620.1
NW_022983508.1 RefSeq CDS 4215 5392 . - 0 ID=cds-XP_033376609.1
NW_022983512.1 RefSeq CDS 2650 3267 . + 0 ID=cds-XP_033376596.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'p9!=$9{if(p0) print p0} !a[$9]++; {p9=$9; p0=$0} END{print p0}' file | 
  awk 'NR%2{k=($7=="+")?4:5; v=$k; next} {$k=v}1'

NW_022983499.1 RefSeq CDS 6883 7503 . + 0 ID=cds-XP_033376633.1
NW_022983500.1 RefSeq CDS 5353 7994 . + 0 ID=cds-XP_033376630.1
NW_022983502.1 RefSeq CDS 5391 7408 . + 0 ID=cds-XP_033376626.1
NW_022983504.1 RefSeq CDS 5059 5513 . - 0 ID=cds-XP_033376620.1
NW_022983508.1 RefSeq CDS 4215 5392 . - 1 ID=cds-XP_033376609.1
NW_022983512.1 RefSeq CDS 2650 3267 . + 0 ID=cds-XP_033376596.1
```

two separate scripts will simplify the logic, first one prints the first and last rows for each key (duplicates if a single line is present).  Second script picks the right values based on the sign.

Answer (score 1):

another `awk` (also added printing zeroes for $8 as commented)

```
> cat tst.awk
$9 == prev {
    $keep = val
    $8 = 0
    row = $0
    next
}

{ 
    print row
    prev = $9
    $8 = 0
    row = $0
    keep = ( $7=="+"? 4: 5 )
    val = $keep
}

END {
    print row
}
```

Output:

```
> awk -f tst.awk file

NW_022983499.1 RefSeq CDS 6883 7503 . + 0 ID=cds-XP_033376633.1
NW_022983500.1 RefSeq CDS 5353 7994 . + 0 ID=cds-XP_033376630.1
NW_022983502.1 RefSeq CDS 5391 7408 . + 0 ID=cds-XP_033376626.1
NW_022983504.1 RefSeq CDS 5059 5513 . - 0 ID=cds-XP_033376620.1
NW_022983508.1 RefSeq CDS 4215 5392 . - 0 ID=cds-XP_033376609.1
NW_022983512.1 RefSeq CDS 2650 3267 . + 0 ID=cds-XP_033376596.1
```